# VBA. Comparing values of columns names in two separate worksheets, copy nonmatching columns to third worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

So, I've explored a few answered VBA Questions, but I'm still stuck. I have three sheets "By_Oppt_ID", "Top_Bottom" and "Non_Top_Bottom". The first two have a large amount of columns each with a unique name. Now there are some columns in By_Oppt_ID that aren't in "Top_Bottom". So I want to compare each column name in By_Oppt_ID to every column name in "Top_Bottom", and if the column name isn't found, copy that column name and all the rows beneath it, to a third worksheet "Non_Top_Bottom". 
So Here's what I have:

```
Sub Copy_Rows_If()

    Dim Range_1 As Worksheet, Range_2 As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range



    Set Range_1 = Workbooks("Complete_Last_Six_Months_Q_Results.xlsx").Sheets("Top_Bottom")
    Set Range_2 = Workbooks("Complete_Last_Six_Months_Q_Results.xlsx").Sheets("By_Oppt_ID")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Stays on the same screen even if referencing different worksheets

    For Each c In Range_2.Range("A2:LX2")
            ' Checks for values not in Range_1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range_1.Range("A1:CR1"), c.Value) = 0 Then
            ' If not, copies rows to new worksheet
            ' LR = .Cells(Row.Count, c).End(xUp).Row
                c = ActiveCell
                Sheets("By_Oppt_ID").Range("Activecell", "ActiveCell.End(xlDown)").Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Complete_Last_Six_Months_Q_Results.xlsx").Sheets("Non_Top_Bottom").Range("A1:A6745")
            Set rgPaste = rgPaste.Offset(0, 1) 'Moves to the next col, but starts at the same row position

        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

I've compiled this many ways and keep getting a series of errors: Subscript Out of Range/ Method "Global_Range" Failure. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does your code do? where does it fail? what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have this code within the same workbook every time, try using

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Top_Bottom")
```

instead of

```
Workbooks("Complete_Last_Six_Months_Q_Results.xlsx").Sheets("Top_Bottom")
```

replicate that through your code and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `c = Activecell`? Do you mean to say `c.activate`?

You might then also want to change the next line to
`Sheets("By_Oppt_ID").Range(Activecell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Copy Workbooks("Complete_Last_Six_Months_Q_Results.xlsx").Sheets("Non_Top_Bottom").Range("A1")`